# PHP / Comparing two statements containing conditions to get if it's true or false

Tags: php

I am trying to compare two statements in PHP. After that I need to check if their output is true or false.

I will start by explaining with a little example for more clarifications.
let's say we have:

```
$statement1 = '(p == 5 || p == 8) && (r == 01 || r == 06)';
$statement2 = '(p == 5)(r == 01)'; // yes, it doesn't contain an &&
```

I need to compare $statement2 with $statement1 and have the result as true  because (p == 5) in $statement2 is true according to the first part of $statement1 (p == 5 || p == 8) AND (r == 01) in $statement2 is true according to the second part of $statement1 (r == 01 || r == 06). So in a nutshell, I should get a true for those statements.

So what I thought of is to take the value between parentheses of the two statements and store them in arrays with the following code

PS: $text_outside was created in case it's needed

```
function extract($string)
   {
    $text_outside=array();
    $text_inside=array();
    $t="";
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($string);$i++)
    {
        if($string[$i]=='(')
        {
            $text_outside[]=$t;
            $t="";
            $t1="";
            $i++;
            while($string[$i]!=')')
            {
                $t1.=$string[$i];
                $i++;
            }
            $text_inside[] = $t1;

        }
        else {
            if($string[$i]!=')')
            $t.=$string[$i];
            else {
                continue;
            }

        }
    }
    if($t!="")
    $text_outside[]=$t;

    return $text_inside; 
  }
```

That will be applied for both statements. I will then loop through the arrays created for the comparison. but then I am stuck. I am unable to compare both statements to get if it's true or false.

That's the remaining part:

```
$extractedStatement1[] = extract($statement1);
$extractedStatement2[] = extract($statement2);

foreach ($statement2 as $val2){
    foreach ($statement1 as $val1){
        //I am stuck here
    }
}
```

I need to get at the end if the $statement2 is true or false according to $statement1. I am open to other approaches as well.

Comment: I've read your question multiple times and i'm still confused. To clarify, your 2 statements are strings, you would like to get the results of both strings (like if they were an arithmetic problem) then compare the 2 together?  edit: I think i might understand, you have 2 statement, 1 if conditions and 1 variable attribution and both of them are formulated as strings.

Comment: yes @CedricGuindon that's it. Any idea how I might do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Symfony's ExpressionLanguage component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html) after transforming `$statement2` into a `var -> value` associative array:

```
use Symfony\Component\ExpressionLanguage\ExpressionLanguage;

$statement1 = '(p == 5 || p == 8) && (r == 01 || r == 06)';
$statement2 = '(p == 5)(r == 01)';

$assignments = [];
if (preg_match_all('/\((\w+) == (\w+)\)/', $statement2, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
  foreach ($matches as [, $var, $val]) {
    $assignments[$var] = $val;
  }
}

$expressionLanguage = new ExpressionLanguage();
var_dump($expressionLanguage->evaluate($statement1, $assignments));  // true
```

**[Demo](https://phpsandbox.io/n/tight-disk-j00k)**

Edit: if you need to handle `!=` too then the following should do:

```
$assignments = [];
if (preg_match_all('/\((\w+) ([!=])= (\w+)\)/', $statement2, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
  foreach ($matches as [, $var, $operator, $val]) {
    $assignments[$var] = $operator === '=' ? $val : null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Jeto . That's what I needed.

Comment: if you don't mind I have a question as I am not familiar in symfony. for  $statement1= '(Item == 15702) && (Country != 1)' and $statement2 = '(Item == 15702)(Country != 1)' -> I am getting Uncaught Symfony\Component\ExpressionLanguage\SyntaxError: Variable "Country" is not valid around position 21 for expression `(Item == 15702) && (Country != 1).  Although I edited regular expression to /\((\w+) == (\w+)\)|\((\w+) != (\w+)\)/

Comment: @ArtemMorrot I've edited my answer with a solution that should handle `!=`.

Comment: Thank you! @jeto